# How to store and download a zip file in database postgres

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I'm trying to store and then download a zip file from Postgres database. I know that this is not the best approach (i should only save the path to file) but i need to do this way, just for learning and practice.

I did a python script to store the content of the file into a bytea field but this was not my final goal. I really want to know how to save the zip file.

Any ideas? I just know python so i'm trying to this in python

Thank you guys!

Comment: Why would you want to download it in the database, that's a horrible idea. If the server takes a long time to respond, it'll tie up your database handle. Moreover, there is no reason for it. Have something outside the database download the file, if it succeed put the row in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you can store the file as a bytea field then storing a zipped file is just the same.

Postgres doesn't have a concept of "file" field - you simply store the content (as you did for the original content) in bytea field.

If you're asking about zipping a file on the fly,
Take a look at [zlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#module-zlib) it's one of the common modules for such tasks.

Regards 
Jony

Comment: Ow so easy! thank you! But now how can i download this gz file? @cohenjo

Comment: Select the butea column and dump the content to a file.